# SQL to generate a serial number from 1 to 9 repeatedly in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I need generate serial number in Oracle SQL Query..

Example:

```
rownum (1,2..9,10,11..18,19,20..N)

my_srl_no (1,2..9,1,2..9,1,2..N)
```

Comment: And what is the limit of `N`?

Comment: N -- last record of table

Comment: `select mod(rownum - 1, 9) + 1, t.* from table t;`

Comment: Thank you so much..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the modulo function `MOD` (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/MOD.html#GUID-E12A3928-2C50-45B0-B8C3-82432C751B8C).

If it's really `rownum` you want to deal with:

```
mod(rownum - 1, 9) + 1
```

but usually you would rather use `ROW_NUMBER` in order to number your rows by some sort criteria. Anyway, the math stays the same.